# Assets Precompilation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, precompile

I tried precompiling app assets in production mode but instead of getting one stylesheet and one javascript file, i got a zipped version of each stylesheet and each javascript file in the assets folder in the public directory.
Any suggestions on how to precompile assets in the way they are meant to be?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! it might help to put some information about what command line or gui options you are using (i'm not a ruby guy).

Comment: Also add your Rails version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View the source of the web page in browser, look for files in the format of `application-6080907526369cfb5b4.css` and `application-1c1aeb834ae6289d02ed5499.js`. If you can find these files it means, the assets are being precompiled and being used. There are many files which are being created when you check the folders which includes files with an extension `.js.gz` and `.css.gz` in case you are on a unix m/c.

I would suggest you to refer :  [asset pipeline provides a framework to concatenate and minify or compress JavaScript and CSS assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

From the [Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html),

> When files are precompiled, Sprockets also creates a gzipped (.gz) version of your assets. Web servers are typically configured to use a moderate compression ratio as a compromise, but since precompilation happens once, Sprockets uses the maximum compression ratio, thus reducing the size of the data transfer to the minimum